# auto channel forward telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

In telegram you can have channels in which millions can receive massages instantly. Then you have the strong API to create bots do anything. One could be a bot to imitate anything published to a (source) channel through your (destination) channel.
There has been a really good job done by [aahnik](https://github.com/aahnik) for an automation bot that forward (or resend) any massage sent to a telegram channel. You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/aahnik/tgcf).

Any thing the source channel publishes would be sent to destination channel. but there is something i want to add to it. if the source channel sent a reply to its previously published massage then the massage is sent as a new massage not a reply . i want it to be a reply ([telethon reply method](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html?highlight=reply#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.reply)).

Comment: Thank you for asking this question as it helped me find such a good repo. Now about your question, if I understood correctly you want to add a feature to that repo? If so then StackOverflow is not the right place to ask such questions. Open a github issue over there and after a discussion with that repo's owner, you may proceed with making a PR.

Comment: as you mentioned i opened an issue and aahnik have kindly add this featured to that amazing repo.

Comment: can you post the issue link here?

Comment: there it is: https://github.com/aahnik/tgcf/discussions/67

Comment: I think you may answer your question and accept it, to make it clear for others.